# Java - Change values of an array by a method in a Class

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Here is my code:

```
class Myclass {

    private static int[] array;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Myclass m = new Myclass();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            m.array[i] = i;
            System.out.println(m.array[i]);
        }
    }

    public Myclass() {
        int[] array = new int[10];
    }
}
```

It throws a `java.lang.nullPointerException` when trying to do this:

```
m.array[i] = i;
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared a local variable `array` in your constructor, so you're not actually initializing the `array` declared in `Myclass`.

You'll want to refer directly to `array` in the constructor.  Instead of

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Use this

```
array = new int[10];
```

Additionally, you've declared `array` static in the scope of your `Myclass` class.

```
private static int[] array;
```

You only have one instance of `Myclass` here, so it doesn't matter, but normally this would not be static, if you're initializing it in a constructor.  You should remove `static`:

```
private int[] array;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your constructor you are making your assignment to a local variable names array, not the static class variable also named array. This is a scope problem.

I'm also guessing that since you access array via m.array, you want a member variable and not a static one. Here's the fix

```
class Myclass {

  private int[] array;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myclass m = new Myclass();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        m.array[i] = i;
        System.out.println(m.array[i]);
    }
  }

  public Myclass() {
        rray = new int[10];
  }

}
```

Comment: +1, I didn't downvote your answer, but your answer is correct.

Comment: @rgettman I wasn't accusing you, at the time every answer was at 0. I also upvoted yours.

Comment: That's ok.  But I figured others might read it like it was, because at the time my answer was the only one with a positive score.

Answer (score 0):

in `MyClass()` type this

```
this.array = new int [10];
```

instead of this

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as below. In the constructor, instead of initializing the instance variable you created a new local variable and the instance variable was left uninitalized which caused the NullPointerException. Also the instance variable shouldn't be static.

```
class Myclass {

  private int[] array;

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Myclass m = new Myclass();
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    m.array[i] = i;
    System.out.println(m.array[i]);
 }
}

public Myclass() {
      array = new int[10];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you plan to use `array` as a field of `m` (i.e. `m.array`) don't declare it as `static`, but:

```
private int[] array;
```

Next thing you have to do is to initialize it. Best place to do that is in the constructor:

```
public MyClass() {
    array= new int[10]; //just array = new int[10]; don't put int[] in front of the array, because the variable already exists as a field.
}
```

The rest of the code should work.